# Optimize MySQL query and index for multiple column range query

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, order-by

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobs` (
    `job_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `job_status` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
    `lease_date` datetime,
    `priority` int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`job_id`),
    INDEX `job_status_priority_lease_date` (`job_status`, `priority`, `lease_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

The full query I want to perform on the table would be the following:

```
select * from jobs 
where job_status="IN_PROGRESS"
and lease_date<"10minutesago"
order by 
priority
limit 100
```

I am implementing database as a job queue. 10 min is like the job time out, I only want to act on the jobs that are already timed out. Jobs has different priority so I was ordering by it. Also, I want to make my DB job queue behave like FIFO, that's why my index includes `lease_date`.

I definitely want my results to be ordered by Priority, e.g. two chunks of the results with Priority 0 and 1. I don't need my results to be strictly ordered by `lease_date`, as long as they are Ascending order in their own chunks that is good enough for me. e.g. result set:

```
priority lease_date
0        2017-08-19
0        2018-09-20
1        2016-08-20
1        2018-10-20
```

Is my index enough for that? How much can I optimize the query and build an index to boost the performance as much as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `"10minutesago"` do you mean `NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE`?

`order by priority DESC` sorts *only* on `priority`.  The ordering within it is unpredictable.  It might be ascending, it might be descending, or seemingly random.

Your `INDEX(job_status, priority, lease_date)` won't get as far as `lease_date`.  It will take care of `where job_status="IN_PROGRESS"` and it *might* then walk through the rows in `priority` order.  But that's all.

You *could* say `ORDER BY priority DESC, lease_date DESC`, but `and lease_date < "10minutesago"` will not make use of the index.

Think of building an index thus:  First have any number of columns tested with `=`.  Then have *one* range column.

**(After OP's edit)**

Your example implies that you need

```
ORDER BY priority ASC, lease_date ASC
```

As for the question of efficiency, ...

The `WHERE` clause needs

```
INDEX(job_status, lease_date)  -- in this order; adding `priority` won't help
```

If the optimizer would prefer to focus on the `ORDER BY`, then

```
INDEX(job_status, priority, lease_date)  -- in this order
```

Notes:

- `job_status` is first because it is tested with `=`.
- Tacking on just `lease_date` makes it possible to handle the entire `WHERE` in the index.  But there will still be an "filesort" to handle the `ORDER BY`.
- Tempting the Optimizer to focus on the `ORDER BY` with the second index (to avoid the filesort) may or may not backfire.  It depends on how much of the data needs to be skipped over because of the `lease_date` filter.

If you have a thousand rows in the table, simply add both indexes; the query will be "fast enough".  If you have a million rows, then you are stuck with a tough problem and should rethink the queuing mechanism.  No matter what you do with the indexes, occasionally the wrong index will be used and the query will run painfully slow.  Be aware that a hiccup in the system can make a queue sporadically jump from a civilized number of entries to a huge number.

Do you imply that this table is a "queue"?  How long does it take to perform an item in the queue?  If it is a "short" time, then "Don't queue it, just do it".

**Add `priority` to WHERE**

If you change to

```
select * from jobs 
    where job_status = "IN_PROGRESS"
      AND priority = 1
    and lease_date < NOW() - 10 MINUTE
    order by priority
    limit 100
```

then either of these becomes optimal:

```
INDEX(job_status, priority, lease_date)
INDEX(priority, job_status, lease_date)
```

See [*my Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) for discussion.

If you have a mixture of with and without `priority`, then have these two:

```
INDEX(job_status, lease_date),
INDEX(job_status, priority, lease_date)
```

The Optimizer will pick between them.

Comment: I thought the index would be sorted by default and MySQL would be able to use that. That's why I had the index as `job_status_priority_lease_date`, I thought MySQL would be able to visit priority in order, and find the boundary lease_date and then pick out the results that's has the earliest timestamp. If that is the case, how can I optimize my query and result? I will revise my question

Comment: @JialunLiu - If you want an ordering, you must specify it.  I added a lot to my Answer.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer! Each single job could take from 10s to 1 min, that's why I needed a queue. What if I change the query to put `priority` as part of the where clause, like `select * from jobs where priority=0 and priority=1`? Would that be able to fully use the index `INDEX(job_status, priority, lease_date)`. And since index are sorted in the ascending order, I would get the result set I want?

Comment: @JialunLiu - I added more.

Comment: Sorry I actually meant the query to be `select * from jobs where (priority=0 or priority=1)`? Would mysql choose to use the index `INDEX(job_status, priority, lease_date)` by any chance?

Comment: @JialunLiu - That's a tricky one.  And I don't know the answer.  Suggest you try both, then add the results to your Question.  It _may_ even depend on what version of MySQL you are using.

Comment: Yep, I will try that, thanks for your help!